# Elasticsearch set up 32bit service. But my OS and java version is 64

Tags: java, elasticsearch

```
service.bat install
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\java" -version
find: 64-Bit: No such file or directory
Installing service : "elasticsearch-service-x86"
Using JAVA_HOME (32-bit): "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31"
The service 'elasticsearch-service-x86' has been installed.

JAVA version
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\java" -version
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem on Windows 7 with Elasticsearch 1.4.3 : it is due to the fact that I am using a shell with Gnu Find and not directly windows shell.

The 2 parameters of the find command are reversed.

I succeeded to install and launch the service with windows classic shell.

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Elastisearch's service.bat file and replace "find" with "C:\Windows\System32\find.exe" (or wherever your Windows find.exe is located).

Reason: You probably have Cygwin, Ruby or any other tool installed that provides its own "find" command earlier in your path.